# Outlook pst file - password read

Tags: c++, outlook, passwords

I would like to know how can I recover/read password from pst file ?

I read some articles which found that password in pst file is implemented by CRC32.

It is ok, but I would like to know where this password is included in pst file ?
I have to know position of this password in this file.

I was wondering that maybe You will be have some information about “algorithm of read pst password…How to…?”

Could you be so kind and send me any information about it ?

I am not interested in any written software like PST .NET or something application which can help to return back your password, I want to know how can I write it in C++ language by myself...

Please give me a clue for this...

I am looking forward to mailing from You.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210.aspx) on the format of PST files.  The [password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385916%28v=office.12%29) itself is stored in a particular property in the message store.